# AWS AMI Neo4j Backups

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, neo4j

I am running the [official AMI](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B071P26C9D?qid=1572263840999&sr=0-1&ref_=srh_res_product_title) provided by Neo4j on AWS.

I would like to backup the Database regularly to s3, but i am not really sure where to start.

Ideally if the AMI could have a scheduled task to auto backup to s3 that would be best, can i setup a Shell script something like [this](https://blog.quent.in/blog/2014/07/11/backup-neo4j-database-to-aws-s3/) ? How do i ensure it stays installed and scheduled on the AMI machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Took some time to understand and then edit the script that i linked to in the original post.

The main take away was that there is no way to backup the DB while it is online, so you need a script that takes it offline copies the contents of graph.db and then restarts the DB.

Link to an updated [Gist](https://gist.github.com/darrynhoskingluna/6628ac30b03187b94456851e13840c97)